# How to remove letter in front of the word laravel

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

Based on the picture above is the result of var_dump() and dd() of the same variable ,when i var_dump() , the apostrophe (') symbol is in black diamond of question mark ,
but when i dd() the same variable , the apostrophe can be seen clearly but
letter 'b' suddenly appear in front of the words

what i want is can someone help me to get the result :

> LOREAL's SDN BHD

and at the same time i want to remove all special character (**excluding** these 4 symbols (-) ,(_) ,('),(,) )

Answer (score 0):

Simply escape the special character will resolve the issue.
Just do `mysqli_real_escape_string` this will resolve the issue.
Like

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($request()->user);
```

Or use `addslashes function()`

```
$name = addslashes($request()->user);
```

Comment: i already give it a try addslashes() function, it's still not giving the result i want  and mysqi_real_escape_string() i cannot use this because i not using mysqi